# Google Maps V3 Using Reimer ASP.NET Control

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I'm using the ASP.NET control from reimers.dk and I was able to view the map, add zoom/pan controls. Panning and zooming work fine from within the map. My problem is getting the map to center on a point sent from ASP.NET, like from a button click. There is no effect or change to  the map. Any help with this is appreciated.

Here is the page and code behind:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>


<%@ Register assembly="Reimers.Google.Map" namespace="Reimers.Google.Map" tagprefix="Reimers" %>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>


                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"  Text="Button" />


                <Reimers:Map ID="Map1" runat="server" Width="600" Height="400" DefaultMapType="Terrain">
    <Center Latitude="51.477" Longitude="0.0" />

</Reimers:Map>     

      </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//////////////////////////////////////

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Map1.MapControls.Add(new Reimers.Google.Map.Controls.ZoomControl());
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Map1.SetCenter(new Reimers.Google.Map.LatLng(27, -82));

    }
}
```

I also tried with js, without this control. I got similar results..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help to see the code you're using to make the center call.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure this out. This code works for me to set the center in the `Page_Load` method:

```
LatLng laln = new LatLng();
laln.Latitude = 65;
laln.Longitude = -19;
Map1.Center = laln;
```